# Latest Raspbian 10 Buster flashed onto 32gb micro sd card not booting Pi 1 Model B

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card, raspbian-buster, pi-1

Flashed using a 4gb sd card with slightly older release of the same buster os with `dd`, which itself boots fine on the same model B.

But when I attempt to boot using the latest legacy buster lite os (300 odd MB image) on a micro sd mounted via sd adapter there is no response from the pi. Red power light on but no boot activity.

Is it something to do with using a 32GB micro sd via sd adapter on the old pi 1 model B?

Comment: The absolute minimum size for an SD card is 8GB. Even a 16GB card is a bit small. The ideal size is 32GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two logical partitions written to sda1 as I mistakenly wasn't writing to top level sda. When I cleared these using fdisk and set the dd of to /dev/sda and not /dev/sda1 the card booted fine.